# How to set any type on unstructured object?

Tags: typescript, types

In the below example I get the type error on `obj[oid]`

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '2'
> can't be used to index type '{}'.

I imagine that I somehow have to specify that all the elements in the `obj` object are `any`, as I don't know the objects structure before hand?

```
import * as TOML from '@iarna/toml';
import * as fs from 'fs';

function readToml(filename: string): object {
  return TOML.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'));
}

const obj = readToml('./output/obj.toml');

const oid = 2;
const offerId = 1;

console.log(obj[oid].offers[offerId]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you don't know the structure of an object at compile-time, you probably want to reach for the [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type). For instance, in this case you might make the return type of the `readToml` function `Record<string, any>`, which says "An object whose properties have string keys and `any` values."

```typescript
function readToml(filename: string): Record<string, any> {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return TOML.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'));
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wCoHkCyAZOAMyghDgHIABYZKAO2QHoZSAbcgbgChRJZEU6QkJJlywzly6EArnQDGMYBDpwoAU2QATDGwAUhYK3UMQ6gFxxUMKMDoBzAJSWASuvnQtAHmu2HAGhQ6AE8APjgAby5GRjhAJCIExKTklNSUgD1MrOyc7K44ArV1GBl6TFw8ADowWlR1A1RKjW0AMSN1AGVghQN203VA8hkYQgBaAA5yR0duAF8pDzprOAgAIwArOABeIu1dEFY9ckrGCGGwYdONypYDqe4uReWIYC1tuAAmbif4CEJCdRQACSbx2AEYHk8IMZKqwIPY9Gt1gBtF5aAC6lT+AKgqFR-0BIPRMyAA)

If you don't even know for sure it'll be an object, you'd use `any`, or if you know it will be just one of several types, you'd use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those types. For example, if you knew that you'd get back either a `Record<string, any>` or a `string` (but not, say, a `number` or `boolean`), you could use the type `Record<string, any> | string` to express that at the type level. (That's not likely in this case, it's just meant as an example for other situations.)

Comment: I know that it will always be a key/value structured object, so `Record<string, any>` is the one to use?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting - Yes. The `any` on the values is wide open, could be anything. Depending on what you know about the values of the properties, you might be able to be a bit more narrow. For instance, if you know it's an object and that the only possible property values are strings and numbers, you could use `Record<string, string | number>`. But if you don't know what the property values will be, you probably have to resort to `any`.